# Установка Ubuntu по сети

Tags: установка, ubuntu

Доброе время суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить линукс (желательно Ubuntu) по сети? Желательно чтобы было от А до Я.

На гугл отправлять не надо - искал не только там. Находил, пробовал, но все как-то не получалось.

Дошел до того, что клиент цепляется к DHCP, но далее выдавало вроде PXE-T01: File not found.

Но затем несколько ковыряний - и опять не могу подцепиться по DHCP.

Пробовал кучу вариантов, поэтому сейчас куча разных настроек - какие нужны, какие нет - не знаю. Т.е. советы типа - "в этом месте вставьте такую-то строчку" уже не помогут.

Заранее спасибо)

Стоит Ubuntu 12.04.

**UPD: Как я ставил** ([Ubuntu по-русски](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_ubuntu_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8))

- sudo apt-get install aptitude
- sudo aptitude -R install apache2 atftpd tftpd-hpa dhcp3-server

У меня стоял tftpd-hpa, при установке atftpd говорит:

*Необходимо получить 0 Б/62,0 kБ архивов. После распаковки 186 kБ будет занято.Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости: tftpd-hpa : Конфликтует: atftpd но будет установлен 0.7.dfsg-11.Следующие действия разрешат зависимости:*

*Удалить следующие пакеты: 1) tftpd-hpa*

Ну это ладно, в установке tftpd-hpa вроде не используется (по документации задаем только конфиг для него)

- правим конфиги как описано в документации
- делаем sudo /etc/init.d/atftpd start

Смотрим логи atftpd - "atftpd: invalid IP address". Параметр bind-address не указан, по ману - "--bind-address <IP address>              Specify the IP address which atftpd binds to. Useful when --dae‐              mon is specified. Default is to bind to all interfaces. Only one              address can be specified, the server can only listen to  one  or              all interfaces."

Т.е. должен слушать все интерфейсы, а не вываливаться с ошибкой.

- делаем вид, что atftpd был добавлен случайно, удаляем его, ставим tftpd-hpa. Смотрим - в процессах висит.
- настраиваем веб-сервер апач
- настраиваем DHCP сервер.

Здесь возникла еще одна проблема - "После этого нужно сказать нашему DHCP серверу слушать один из интерфейсов. Для этого откройте файл /etc/default/dhcp3-server и добавьте..."

Ну нету у меня этого файла /etc/default/dhcp3-server... И че делать? Игнорим пока что...

- sudo /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server start

Команда не найдена... М-да... Поэтому /etc/default/dhcp3-server и отсутствует...

Причем сам-то dhcp3-server стоит, никуда не делся он. А вот как с ним работать?

В общем провалился этот способ. Следуя документация ничего сделать не получилось...

***Посмотрев на возникающие ошибки, сделал следующим образом:***

1. Убрал из установки atftpd
2. Вместо ковыряний с dhcp3-server делал все для dhcp
3. Сразу не обратил, да и из текста это не понятно - указано только в примерах, но требуется Alternate диск. До этого я пробовал обычную KDE, и туда пытался добавить netboot - че-то не получилось
4. В итоге получил готовый сервер - клиентская машина получила ip, началась установка. В статье вроде не написано, но догадаться было не сложно - при указании сервера, с которого будут качаться пакеты - указывать свой.

Правда в тот самый момент, когда установка уже шла, мне выскочило сообщение, что "natty/restricted/binary-i386 corrupted". На этом месте комп завис.

Перезагрузился - опять ошибка на этом же месте и комп перестает реагировать на что-либо. Дистрибутив - с офсайта. В чем может быть проблема?

Ставил 11.04, буду пробовать 12.04 - может поможет, хотя restricted/binary-i386 там идентичный

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам подробно писал когда то статью на своем блоге [как это сделать](http://nosensus.blogspot.com/2011/07/debian-lan.html)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то dhcpd запускать надо так:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

Comment: Я поэтому и просил "от А до Я" - по тому, что в инете даже на офсайтах - ничего не получалось.Вот как оказалось dhcp3-server вообще отсутствует (ну или по крайней мере не нужен)

Comment: Ну тогда конкретная инструкция из того же гуглаhttp://annenkov.org/nastrojka-pxe-servera-dlya-ustanovki-ubuntu-po-seti/

Answer (score 0):

Ну [вот](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_ubuntu_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) же!! ну честно, первая ссылка в гугле

Comment: Скажу больше, пробовал [это](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/install-tftp.html) (офсайт) и [это](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s01.html.en#boot-tftp) (debian)  и [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/53276/) (хабр)По вашей ссылке - `sudo /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server start` - у меня этого нет, только dhcpd, а строчка `sudo aptitude -R install apache2 atftpd tftpd-hpa dhcp3-server` вообще вылетает с ошибкой разрешения зависимостей.Насколько понял, atftpd и tftpd-hpa - по сути одно и тоже, для работы достаточно одно из них.

Comment: что значит "вылетает с ошибкой разрешения зависимостей"? может как-то разрешить зависимости?

Comment: Судя по всему тут два варианта:а)много и вдумчиво читать;б)заплатить кому-нибудь кто настроит сервер.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, обновил вопрос.Зависимости не разрешаются - одно требует удаления другого)"Разрешением" в данном случае был полный отказ от одного из tftp-серверов.